# Is my CPU performing as it should?

Tags: cpu, troubleshooting, fps

Recently my frames in a game I play have dropped significantly. I am trying to troubleshoot this and have got the the stage of the CPU, as you can see I have an Core i7 3770k, and although I know a bit about computers, I am not completely down with the nitty-gritty of all the numbers. Is it me or is this core speed quite low and if so could this be the reason why my frames have been lowered?

Please see image below:

[image: CPU-Z]

Comment: your CPU is throttling itself because of a temperature problems

Comment: @Ramhound: How do you figure? CPU-Z does not measure any thermal sensors. It is entirely possible that the CPU is simply scaling its frequency back because the workload is more or less idle. It would be more important to see the results while a CPU-heavy application is running (e.g. said game).

Comment: The frequency of the CPU is not going to throttle itself over 1.2 Ghz just because it's not under a load.  The CPU in question is a 3.4 Ghz chip.  The product also is a non-mobile product

Comment: @Ramhound: Sure it is, Intel's Core microarchitecture is designed to work precisely that way. While idle, it will use the lowest clock multiplier supported. It does not matter whether the CPU is mobile or not, all modern x86 CPUs do this. From Intel Atom on up to Intel Xeon. GPUs work this way as well, AMD calls it "zero core" - as long as the GPU is idle, it uses the lowest clock rate it can possibly support. See my updated answer - I am using a workstation class x86 CPU (definitely not mobile) and it actually has a wider range of frequency scaling based on load than the OP's CPU.

Comment: Apart from all the discussion, have you checked GPU performance? Game frames typically depend more on GPU AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned elsewhere, this is likely normal. Modern CPUs employ frequency scaling (per-core) based on workload. This reduces unnecessary thermal wear and tear and power draw. As illustrated in your screenshot, your CPU has a range of frequencies for scaling: 16x - 39x and it is sitting at 16x. To me, this implies that your system is completely idle.

Under high workloads the frequency will scale up to 35x (the nominal clock rate for the CPU core) and under extreme workloads when the CPU is not too hot it will actually overclock itself temporarily. Intel calls this "Turbo Boost", and the remaining 4x clock multipliers are reserved for this state. If you have a good cooling solution, this "boosted" frequency may actually be your normal clock rate under peak load.

I would not make a habit of measuring your CPU frequency while the operating system is not doing any work, because that is when the frequency will be at its lowest. You should look at the frequency while a game is running.

Having said that, as a graphics professional I can tell you that low framerate these days is typically due to GPU and not CPU, unless of course you have an integrated graphics solution (in which case, the CPU may physically be coupled to the GPU). Modern ***dedicated*** GPUs also employ frequency scaling based on load and thermal state, and likewise there exists a program: [**GPU-Z**](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) that is analogous to CPU-Z in your diagram.

#### UPDATE:

Since there was some disbelief in this behavior in comments, I decided to include a diagram of my own CPU under idle and moderate work load. My particular hardware is overclocked to begin with (default clock multiplier is 43 instead of 36), but you can see this is ***far*** from a mobile processor (it is effectively a re-branded Xeon workstation/server CPU) and the CPU still does frequency scaling based on load.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all these replies, proving to be really useful - do you have any suggestions on programs to stress test the cpu or would you just say opening a bunch of applications is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

Your core speed is only at about half of what it can be.  This could be entirely normal - if you are not heavily using a CPU it automatically goes slower to reduce heat and power.

The alternative is that it is throttling - if the CPU is running to hot it will throttle down to reduce power and heat and avoid damaging the CPU.  You might want to open your box up see if there is an accumulation of dirt on the heatsink and if so clean it.  (I do a quick and dirty by taking it down to a petrol station with old tire pumps and releasing the air on my rig).    You can also see if the CPU is throttling by running something CPU intensive in the background (I'm not a Windows person, but I'm sure benchmarking tools or a tool to calculate pi or something rendering fractals without GPU support will do it) and watch if the core speed increases.

I guess its also possible that there is an incorrect setting in the bios underclocking the system, but if you havn't played with that, its unlikely.